# Change lables font size when On small device in chart.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, chart.js

I am getting data on iframe and then I used canvas in website to show chat.js data . Code is as follow (this code is generated and took from chrome Elements)

```
 <div class="well" style="padding:15px;">
<iframe class="chartjs-hidden-iframe" tabindex="-1" style="width: 100%; display: block; border: 0px; height: 0px; margin: 0px; position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px;"></iframe>
<canvas id="myChartViolations" width="480" height="560" style="display: block; width: 240px; height: 280px;"></canvas> </div>
```

I have assigned property responsive in chart.js options like this

```
var options = {   
      scaleLabel: function(object) {
      return "      " + object.value;
      },
     responsive: true,
     pointDot: false
      };
```

And angular div properties like this :

```
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
   <div class="well" style="padding:15px;">
   <canvas id="myChartViolations" width="600" height="700"></canvas>
   </div></div>
```

when I have small record it gives good output like this on mobile screen:
[When data is less](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngr7E.png)
But when there is large amount of data :
[When data is large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkwrl.png)
So it starts overlap . Can Someone tell where is I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Which angular version are you exactly using?

Comment: @Akkusativobjekt 1.5.6